# Tezos.amount>Tezos.balance is wrong?

Tags: smart-contracts

is "if (Tezos.amount>Tezos.balance) then" wrong?
Oddly, the condition is failwith when i sent more tez compared to the contract balance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is wrong.

At that point, the `amount` has already been credited to the contract `balance`. Meaning that the `balance` will never be less than the `amount`.

[image]

Comment: Wow! what a cool interface. What do you use? And also how do I compare the amount of tez and the contract balance then?

Comment: The animation above uses visualtez.com with a testing feature coming in May. Looking at what you have above, you probably want something like `Tezos.amount > (Option.unopt (Tezos.balance - Tezos.amount))`.